# Web Botting Web scraping decrypting html

Tags: python, python-requests

Trying to figure out how to build a python bot for school I got the basics but one of the sites I want to scrape its source code is pretty much in entities (not sure if I'm defying it right )

```
 <html data-store="{&quot;app&quot;:{&quot;config&quot;:
 {&quot ;locale&quot;:&quot;en_US&quot;,&quot;bazaarVoiceLocale&quot;:&quot;en_US&quot;,&quot;sitePath&quot;:&quot;u
```

Comment: That is encoding not encryption.

Comment: I made use of the inspect tool I'm an idiot apologies.

Comment: [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) converts the HTML entities to Unicode automatically.

Comment: so it will convert all that code automatically